# Has anyone ever used AOP to detect a circular reference?

Tags: aop, circular-reference

I don't know, so that you could throw a CircularReferenceException?

Comment: I mean I guess you could count the number of times a function was called and see if it seems infinite right?

Or maybe time how long the function has been running?   Doesn't Firefox do something similar to this when a script has stopped responding?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use cflow to mark each method used in that call, and then just store the methods called in a static list in the aspect, to determine if you called the same method again, and depending on how often you call it, you could throw your exception.

I have never tried to do this, and this is just a guess, but it should work.

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html